# Is it expected behavior with "+<space>+" symbol in Apex

Tags: apex

I was checking one of the old codes in the project & found a code where ++ was written. Initially, I thought it might not have executed (it was in if block) so I used the below snippet to confirm and it was working well without any issues. Hence curious to know if is it expected behavior or apex glitch.

```java
String test = 'a' + + 'b';
System.debug('test'+ test);
```

Output -
`HH:MM:SS:mmm USER_DEBUG [2]|DEBUG|testab`

Comment: `String test = 'a' + + + + 'b';` yields same result (true for any number of `+ +`'s)

Comment: There's no Apex Language Specification, so _expected_ is somewhat dubious. The doc says: _If x is a String and y is a String or any other type of non-null argument, concatenates y to the end of x_ , thus the result is unspecified.

Comment: @identigral It's the unary + operator. While not specified in Apex, it's valid in Java, so presumably it comes from higher up.

Comment: @sfdcfox `System.out.println("a" + + "b")` doesn't compile in Java (JDK 17), it produces an operand error.

Comment: @identigral correct. It only works on numbers in Java, as well as most languages. However, Apex just ignores it completely, which is why it works on strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` has two primary uses in most programming languages. The first is the binary addition/concatenation operator, where you have `x + y` either calculates a number or combines strings together, depending on the data types. The second, less common used, is the representation of "positive", and is thus called the unary positive operator, which looks like `+ x`. Its presence is useless in most languages, since numbers written without it are assumed to be positive, but it can indicate intent that a number was meant to be positive. It is provided as the the opposite of the unary negative operator (`- x`), which negates the value of `x`.

Languages that include support for the unary positive operator include C, C++, Java, JavaScript, etc, including Apex. It is not included in the documentation for Apex, but its existence isn't entirely surprising, given how many other languages have this operator.

In Apex, it appears to simply be ignored by the compiler, as you can use it with any data type that you want to:

```
class Example {
}
Example ex = +new Example();
Integer intVal = +42;
String strVal = +'42'; // note: value is "42", not "+42"
Date today = +Date.today();
DateTime now = +DateTime.now();
Time timeVal = +Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

And so on.

Consecutive instances of the unary operator are also ignored.

```
Integer value = + + + + + + + + 1;
```

While this operator doesn't have any specific use functionally, it is nice to be able to communicate in your source that you intended a positive value, rather than by implication.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! It makes sense. However, it seems missing from their operator documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm).

I tried similar with JS, it seems to work for string only when a number is there other wise it's giving NaN all the time. I hope it should be consistent with the other language.

Comment: @YsrShk (a) Not everything Apex can do is in the docs. See `Apex.Stack` as an example. (b) JS is a loosely typed language, and thus has different rules regarding its operators. Further, as I tried to explain, the unary positive operator in Apex is vestigial. Unlike Java and JavaScript, it has literally no function other than as a means of self-documenting positive numbers.